# ActiveMQ Dynamic Queues have dynamicQueues in their name

Tags: activemq-classic, jndi

I am using dynamic queues for testing with names like dynamicQueues/Foo, but in the web console I am seeing the queue names as dynamicQueues/Foo rather than just Foo.

Other code (not ours) uses the same dynamicQueues/Foo but the queue name on the console is just Foo so things are misaligned so to speak.

I have followed the instructions here: http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html

I am confused about whether the queue name reported in the web console should include dynamicQueues or not - finding it hard to debug our problem as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see Foo in the console window, yes.

This code will produce a message on **FOO** and show the queue as FOO in the web console (amq 5.6.0):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
javax.naming.Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
Connection conn = cf.createConnection();
Destination dest = (Destination)ctx.lookup("dynamicQueues/FOO");
Session s = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageProducer prod = s.createProducer(dest);
prod.send(s.createTextMessage("Hello, World!"));
```

Are you sure you are using JNDI to lookup the queue and that you did not configure anything in jndi.properties?

Comment: Can you post the problematic parts of your code? As in my example above, it works with ActiveMQ 5.6.0

Comment: will do. in the meantime I'll mark your answer as correct since it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't respond to the comment above so sorry about answering here.)

This is my problem (in scala):

This works, queue is called FOO
val destination = JmsConnectionFactory.initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/FOO").asInstanceOf[Destination]
val consumer = session.createConsumer(destination)

This doesn't, queue is called dynamicQueues/FOO
val queue = session.createQueue("dynamicQueues/FOO")
val consumer = session.createConsumer(queue)

sigh, it makes sense I guess.